# Cloning files from git gives the error "Too many arguments"

Tags: git, cmd, pyenv

I'm currently trying to set up this Django app:
https://github.com/gothinkster/django-realworld-example-app

When I'm trying to install [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#installation) I get an error.

The git clone code I'm writing in the CMD is: `git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv`

The error I'm getting is this:

```
C:\Users\Erling>git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
fatal: Too many arguments.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]

-v, --verbose         be more verbose
-q, --quiet           be more quiet
--progress            force progress reporting
-n, --no-checkout     don't create a checkout
--bare                create a bare repository
--mirror              create a mirror repository (implies bare)
-l, --local           to clone from a local repository
--no-hardlinks        don't use local hardlinks, always copy
-s, --shared          setup as shared repository
--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]
                      initialize submodules in the clone
--recursive ...       alias of --recurse-submodules
-j, --jobs <n>        number of submodules cloned in parallel
--template <template-directory>
                      directory from which templates will be used
--reference <repo>    reference repository
--reference-if-able <repo>
                      reference repository
--dissociate          use --reference only while cloning
-o, --origin <name>   use <name> instead of 'origin' to track upstream
-b, --branch <branch>
                      checkout <branch> instead of the remote's HEAD
-u, --upload-pack <path>
                      path to git-upload-pack on the remote
--depth <depth>       create a shallow clone of that depth
--shallow-since <time>
                      create a shallow clone since a specific time
--shallow-exclude <revision>
                      deepen history of shallow clone, excluding rev
--single-branch       clone only one branch, HEAD or --branch
--no-tags             don't clone any tags, and make later fetches not to follow them
--shallow-submodules  any cloned submodules will be shallow
--separate-git-dir <gitdir>
                      separate git dir from working tree
-c, --config <key=value>
                      set config inside the new repository
--server-option <server-specific>
                      option to transmit
-4, --ipv4            use IPv4 addresses only
-6, --ipv6            use IPv6 addresses only
--filter <args>       object filtering
--remote-submodules   any cloned submodules will use their remote-tracking branch
--sparse              initialize sparse-checkout file to include only files at root
```

Comment: That command seems to have been written for bash (or maybe bourne shells in general), given that it uses `$(...)` for command substitution. It definitely won't work in `cmd.exe` (which behave *very* different from any bourne-like shell). The simplest way to get this to work is probably to just run it in git-bash.

Comment: What is the output of te command `pyenv root`? Under cmd.exe, you will need to use a `FOR` loop to assign the value to a variable. Yes, I know it is crazy.

Comment: What is the name of your profile folder `%UserProfile%` ? does it contain spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Seems spaces exists in `$(pyenv root)`.

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git "$(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv"
```

BTW, `pyenv` doesn't work on Windows. There's a `pyenv-win` working on Windows. AFAIK `pyenv-virtualenv` is not supported by `pyenv-win`.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I will look up pyenv-win to set up my project